# Definitions and limitations of MapInfo TAB file objects

Tags: mapinfo, geojson, mapbasic

I am working on a MapInfo plugin to convert MapInfo files to GeoJSON files.

I am having trouble matching up the object types of the two formats. Each GeoJSON object type is described in [the documentation](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geometry-objects). The MapInfo object types are a bit more ambiguous. The best I can find is in the MapBasic reference file which says, for example:

- OBJ_INFO_TYPE value: OBJ_TYPE_REGION
- ID: 7
- Object type: Region Object

This is obvious enough but what exactly is a region? Is it analogous to a Polygon? Or is it any closed object?

**Can anyone point me towards a decent definition of each object type?**

**Update 2010-02-03:**

I sent a message to the MapInfo support people who pointed me towards a section in the MapInfo User Guide headed "Map Objects as Part of Layers" which spells things out perfectly. I still can't find this page in the guide that I have (version 10.5) so I'll paste the relevant section below for anyone else in my position.

Quote starts here:

*MapInfo Professional are made up of layers of map objects.
There are five basic types of objects:*

- **Regions:** closed objects that cover a given area. These include polygons, ellipses, and
  rectangles. For example, country boundaries, postal code boundaries, sales territories.
- **Point objects:** represent single
  locations of data. For example,
  customer locations, restaurants,
  parking meters. Points can also be
  combined into multipoint objects.
- **Line objects:** open objects that cover
  a given distance. These include
  lines, polylines, and arcs. Examples
  are streets, rivers, power lines.
- **Text objects:** text that describes a map or another object, such as labels and titles.
- **Collection objects:** combination of region, line, and multipoint objects.

*You can have each type of object in a separate layer (most common), or you can combine
objects in the same layer.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A region in MapInfo (MapBasic) can match a Polygon or a MultiPolygon in GeoJSON. 
For the region to be a polygon it must:
a) only have one polygon or
b) only have one "main" polygon and one or more number of holes

If the region has multiple polygons with zero, one or more holes, I would consider this to be a MultiPolygon.

The GeoJSON describing is quite precise: "*For type "Polygon", the "coordinates" member must be an array of LinearRing coordinate arrays. For Polygons **with multiple rings**, the first must be **the exterior ring** and any others must **be interior rings or holes**.*"

So you would need to check every part of the region to see if it is a hole in the main polygon or an extra polygon.

Answer (score 1):

This Library might be of good use for you.

http://mitab.maptools.org/

http://mitab.maptools.org/mitab-docs/mitab__capi_8cpp.html

Comment: Thanks but I'm programming in MapBasic, the programming language which comes with and was designed specifically for MapInfo, so dealing with MapInfo objects and the TAB format isn't a problem. I just want some more information on the different object types.

Comment: OGR (http://www.gdal.org/ogr/) will convert from Tab to GeoJSON. You can compare your MapBasic output to what OGR produces. This might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't have [FME](http://www.safe.com), or use it for this translation, the documentation will help you here I think.

Check out the [FME Readers and Writers Manual](http://downloads.safe.com/fme/docs/FMEReadersWriters.pdf)

It has info on both MapInfo TAB formats and GeoJSON.

For MapInfo Regions it says:

> MapInfo region features specify area
>   (polygonal) features. The areas that
>   make up a single feature may or may
>   not be disjoint, and may contain
>   polygons which have holes. Each region
>   has a pen style associated with it to
>   control the color, width, and pen
>   pattern used when its boundary is
>   drawn. In addition, a region may set
>   its brush pattern, foreground, and
>   background color to control how the
>   area it encloses will be filled.