# Difference between region and polygon in MapInfo Pro?

Tags: polygon, mapinfo

I am new to using MapInfo 12 and have recently noticed the convert to regions and convert to polyline function.

What is the difference between a region and a polygon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MapInfo, regions include the set of polygons, rectangles, and ellipses.  Don't ask why they consider rectangles to be a special type of polygon, I'll never figure that out.

However, I think you've misread the tool.  It actually says "Convert to Polylines."

[image]

See **[this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/5560/7424)** for more information about MapInfo Map Object Types.

Comment: @Fezter, a rectangle is special in MapInfo because MapInfo Pro doesn't store the coordiantes for all the nodes but stores the min and max coordinates of the rectangle. This also means that the area covered by the rectangle changes depending on the coordinate system. To me, rectangles in MapInfo Pro are cosmetic objects.